# Python: Efficient lookup in a list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.8

I have a huge list of dicts (or objects), that have exactly the same fields. I need to perform a search within this collection to retrieve a single object based on the given criteria (there could be many matches, but I take only the first one).

The search criteria don't care about all the fields, and the fields are often different, so changing the list into a dictionary with hashed values is impossible.

This looks like a job for a database, so I'm thinking about using an in-memory `sqlite` database for it. The problem is that I need to write some kind of wrapper that will translate SQL queries into Python API, which makes me think that perhaps there's already a solution for that somewhere.

Maybe someone already had a similar problem, and there's already a tool that will help me with that? Or `sqlite` is the only way?

Comment: What is "huge"? Have you done any profiling/timing that proves that your current solution is inefficient? What would you consider to be an acceptable level of performance?

Comment: I have around 20 thousand of objects, and I need to search through them quite often. I did profile my application and I've noticed that the collection lookup is the bottleneck. I don't have an acceptable level of performance, the faster the better. I know that the current solution is way too slow.

Comment: 20k objects isn't huge. It should take less than a second to search that, even if several fields need to be tested for a match. You must be using a very inefficient algorithm. Please show the relevant code.

Comment: I don't think I can optimize anything here, here's my lookup function: `next((obj for obj in self._obj_list if lookup_fields.items() <= obj.__dict__.items()), None)`. Anyway, you might be right that this function is just called too often, and the lookup speed is not a problem, but the amount of lookups.

Comment: How is this lookup function used? It's hard to make useful suggestions when there's so little context.